# got undefined in controller while use ng-click on directive template

Tags: angularjs, controller, directive

I did not manage to get the event in parent controller. Tried lot of solutions but always get undefined

Also if I call to that function in link function and from there call to the controller it is not working (but print the object correct in the link function)

thx

Page:

```
<slider update-event="updateEvent(event)"></slider>
```

controller:

```
$scope.updateEvent= function(event) {
    console.log(event);
}
```

directive template:

```
<ul>
    <li  ng-click='updateEvent(event)' ng-repeat="event in events track by $index"><li>
</ul>
```

directive code:

```
restrict: "AE",
templateUrl: "s.html",
replace: true,
scope:{
  updateEvent: '&',
},
link: function (scope,element, attrs, ctrl) {
}
```

Comment: Try to pass function reference in html, i.e. `<slider update-event="updateEvent"></slider>`

Comment: @Slava.K hi  thx  but still not working  now even no "undefined"

Comment: You might use `=` instead of `&`

Comment: @Korte  yes thx  it was part of the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your template to:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-click='updateEvent({event: event})' ng-repeat="event in events track by $index"><li>
</ul>
```

this should be enough (see [here](http://codepen.io/dariospadoni/pen/ALABjr))